# Problem installing pyinstaller with python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller

I can't install pyinstaller with python, each time I try I get the error below:

```
C:\Users\...\Documents\1Work\PCT\ExcelDiff>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/32/0e0de593f129bf1d1e77eed562496d154ef4460fd5cecfd78612ef39a0cc/PyInstaller-3.4.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pz5b1j1k\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
    Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x070D82D0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x070DCC10>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x070DCC30>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x070DCE50>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x070DCD30>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for setuptools
```

Comment: "Connection to pypi.org timed out." <-- looks like you had either a network interruption, or PYPI had a temporary outage, or you had/have a routing issue (proxy, firewall, etc.)

Comment: Check if you have setuptools with:
`easy_install --version`. You could always install it separately with `pip install setuptools`

Comment: Thanks, checked and its installed already: setuptools 28.8.0 from c:\users\linlinho\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (Python 3.6)

Comment: thanks, yes I have set the proxy and no problem installing other 3rd party packages

Comment: finally turned out still a proxy problem, not sure why just not working for pyinstaller. pip installed in home network without proxy and able to install successfully

Answer (score 3):

## Pyinstaller for Python 3.7

**Try below instalation is working of python version 3.7**

```
pip install pyinstaller==4.0 --no-build-isolation
```

Comment: The `--no-build-isolation` flag saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

I'm behind a corporate firewall and had the same issue. Normally, I would install a new python package by invoking pip with the --proxy argument, but somehow for pyinstaller that was not enough.

The solution was that I had to set the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variable in the Command Prompt session, before invoking pip.

In Command Prompt:

> set http_proxy=YourProxyAddress:YourProxyPort
>
> set https_proxy=YourProxyAddress:YourProxyPort
>
> pip --proxy YourProxyAddress:YourProxyPort install pyinstaller